# How to make sales report more "scalable"?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I built an application to keep track of the sales. In my customers view, I want a column with total sales per customer, but as the customer base is growing, the list is loading more and more slowly. This is what I did (simplified):

Controller:

```
$customers = App\Customer::get();
```

View:

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
{{ $customer->name }} {{ $customer->totalSales() }}
@endforeach
```

Model:

```
public function totalSales()
{
     $invoiceLines = InvoiceLine::whereHas('invoice', function ($query) {
        $query->where('customer_id', $this->id);
     })->get();

     $sales = $invoiceLines->reduce(function ($carry, $invoiceLine) {
        return $carry + ($invoiceLine->quantity * $invoiceLine->pricePerUnit);
     });

     return $sales ?: 0;
}
```

What would be the best way to make this view/report more "scalable"?

I have been thinking in creating command that calculates the total sales per customer overnight and put the result in the customer table, but that means that the numbers won't be accurate during the day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems like a very interesting problem.

> I have been thinking in creating command that calculates the total
>   sales per customer overnight and put the result in the customer table

this is a good option.

> but that means that the numbers won't be accurate during the day...

You can keep the numbers accurate by doing the following:
by incrementing the customers table count every time a invoice is made.

This should work for total sales.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have an index on the `customer_id` column.
2. Search for ways to do a "SQL `SUM` on 2 columns using laravel".
3. Try and find some way to do "SQL `SUM` on 2 with a `GROUP BY`. Doing this will replace #2

   - A good way to speed up your application is to avoid making calls to the database in a loop. That is what #3 is suggesting (the loop in this case is the `@foreach` in your View and the database call is the `InvoiceLine::...->get();` in `totalSales()`

---

Adding the index (if missing) and reducing the # of calls to the DB will yield the best results.

I have limited knowledge of Laravel but one way to do this with raw SQL would be:

```
SELECT c.name, ts.totalSales
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(quantity * pricePerUnit) as totalSales
  FROM invoice
  GROUP BY customer_id
) ts ON c.id = ts.customer_id
```

You can see how all the data you're trying to print is pulled at once? I assume you'd want to try and write that using Laravel's Eloquent thingy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above, I came to the following solution:

I created an event: `App\Events\InvoiceSaved` which is dispatched every time an invoice is "touched" (created, updated or deleted). The `App\Events\InvoiceSaved` event will calculate the total sales for the customer and add the result to the customers table (extra field total_sales). Now I can just query my customers table and need to query a relation. The loading time dropped from 7 seconds to 0.5 second!